# active network interface using Sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, interface, wifi

I'm currently working on a windows application that is supposed to communicate with remote embedded systems over WiFi. The Windows application is sending a broadcast message which the remote units are receiving and extract the sender IP from. The remote units then sends an answer back to the extracted IP. The problem is that when sending the broadcast message, C# is using the Wireless Network Connection, but when I open a Socket to listen for the answer (or sending a message to a specified address) it is using the Local Area Connection. Since these interfaces have different IP-adresses the windows application wont receive the answer from the remote.

So my questions are, why are C# using different network interfaces for the different sockets and is there any way of forcing the program to use the same interface for all sockets?

Here is the code for sending the broadcast message

```
    sockB = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);    //Create a UDP socket
    sockB.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);        //Enable broadcast on socket
    IPEndPoint briep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9584);                            //Relate a port to the broadcast address    
    byte[] dat = { 0xAD, 0xEE, BRDCST_CMND, (byte)(0xAD ^ 0xEE ^ BRDCST_CMND) };           //Put in buffer
    sockB.SendTo(dat, briep);              //Broadcast data
```

and here is the code for listening from answers from the remotes

```
    sockC = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);                 //Create an udp socket
    sockC.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 1);                 //set timeout to 5 ms
    sockC.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 1);
    IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999);             //set up an "any" ip address and associate it with port 9854        
    EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)(iep);                                      //Make an endpoint out of previous association
    sockC.Bind(iep);                             //Bind the created socket to listen on port 9854
    byteRecv = sockC.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);                  //Receive on socke
```

Thank you!

Comment: when you say `Local Area Connection` I suppose you mean *Wired Network Connection? Wireless can also be attached to a LAN. If you have the IP, subnet masks and gateways configured correctly, then it should be able to automatically route the connection to your target address.

Comment: I mean the network interface named Local Area Connection in ipconfig. It is connected via a wire to a router. I don't know if IP, subnet masks and gateways are conigured correctly, how can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force it to receive on your wireless adapter, set a more specific IPEndPoint that refers to your wireless adapter:

```
IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("wireless adapter IP here"), 9999);
```

`IPAddress.Any` *should*, as far as I know, listen on all interfaces though, not just pick the highest priority one, so you should be getting the response packets on your wireless adapter the way you have it setup. I guess you can try forcing it using the code above, and if it still doesn't work, then your response UDP messages are just being swallowed somewhere.

Make sure you setup your socket to listen for responses BEFORE you send out your broadcast message, otherwise you might be getting race conditions where the response actually comes before your listener is setup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I realised that my other network card wasn't working properly. I solved it by sending a multicast instead of a broadcast so that the message was sent from the right network interface (the one that does all the other communication with the remotes).